# VBA Custom Class Behaves Like Dim as New

Tags: vba, excel

### Problem

I have a custom class, declared without New, that is acting like it is New. Why? How do I prevent this? What am I doing wrong?

At the code noted "PROBLEM HERE", pPolice will get instantiated on inspection, as though it were declared with New at the top of the class. This means that pPolice is never Nothing, so the If block is never entered, and pPolice is never instantiated the way I intend.

This code is a simplified mock-up to illustrate the problem.

### Code

Custom class, clsPeople, emulates a collection (strongly typed in practice).

```
Private pPeople as Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pPeople = New Collection
End Sub

Public Sub Add(Name as String)
    pPeople.Add Name
End Sub

Public Property Get Count() as Integer
    Count = pPeople.Count
End Property

' Other collection-like functions here...
```

Custom class, clsCivilServants, has different sets of people.

```
Private pPolice as clsPeople
'Private pFire as clsPeople ' Listed to show how the class might work

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pPolice = New clsPeople
End Sub

Public Sub ResetPolice()
    Set pPolice = Nothing
End Sub

Public Property Get Police() as clsPeople
    If pPolice is Nothing Then               ' <---------- Problem Here
        Set pPolice = New clsPeople
        pPolice.Add "Officer Joe" ' Example to show that init worked
    End If

    Set Police = pPolice
End Property
```

### Use Case

1. First time through, with no additions, expect 0 people
2. Add officer Mike, expect 1 person (Mike)
3. Reset police
4. Expect 1 person (Joe)
5. Add officer Tom, expect 2 people (Joe, Tom)

.

```
Dim Springfield as clsCivilServants
Set Springfield = New clsCivilServants

' Step 1
'  look at pPolice: Declared, 0 people

' Step 2
Springfield.Police.Add "Officer Mike"
'  look at pPolice: Declared, 1 person

' Step 3
Springfield.ResetPolice
'  look at pPolice: Nothing, N/A

' Step 4
Debug.Print Springfield.Police.Count
'  observing Police causes declaration of pPolice
'  look at pPolice: Declared, 1 person

' Step 5
Springfield.Police.Add "Officer Tom"
'  look at pPolice: Declared, 2 people
```

Comment: Why do you set pPolice as your custom type in the init sub but as a generic collection later?

Comment: Did you test your mockup? Because there are some errors in it, and when I fixed those it works correctly as expected. `Set pPolice = New Collection` Should be `Set pPolice = New clsPeople`, `clsPeople` needs a `Count` property defined, and to run your use case from another module as should be the case `ResetPolice` needs to be public not private.

Comment: Thanks for tending to my carelessness. I've made the appropriate fixes in the code, and tested on my machine. Unfortunately, the mock-up code does seem to work. I still have the problem in my other code. I'll review and update here...

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to occur only under certain debug circumstances.

- `Springfield.Police` is listed in the VBA Watches pane.
- Code execution stopped inside Property Police
- ResetPolice called while inside Property Police
- Single stepping mode

Really I'm not sure why this happens, but the easy solution of course is to avoid the scenario. Will update this answer if I learn more.